# Cocoapods curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden

Tags: cocoapods

I am facing an issue when trying to get the "SpotX" dependency from Cocoapods that only affects a particular computer. I have tried it on my personal MacBook Pro and it works. However, my Mac Mini is failing.

The Podfile looks like that:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Demo' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Demo
  pod 'SpotX-SDK'
  pod 'SuperAwesome', '7.2.13'
  pod 'SpotX-SDK-AVPlayer'

  target 'DemoTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'DemoUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'DemoTV' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for DemoTV
  pod 'SpotX-SDK-AVPlayer'

  target 'DemoTVTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'DemoTVUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

According to [Here](https://bintray.com/spotxmobile/pods/spotx-sdk-avplayer/view), the version is available

The error message given is:
[image]

The weird part is that is working on other computers with the same Xcode version...

Any ideas?

**DATA**:

```
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Cocoapods version = 1.10.1
```

Comment: Probably a question for SpotX support.

Comment: I have the same issue with different pod, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Nothing yet ... @SeifMeddeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have access to the url of the cocoapod zip file (try it opening it on your browser)

In my case it was a VPN issue, i had to disable VPN to have access to the url, then i tried `pod install` again and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error. Then I referred release notes of Spot SDK [here](https://developer.spotxchange.com/content/local/docs/sdkDocs/Mobile-CTV/iOS/release-notes.md)  and updated my podfile accordingly with 4.10.0.
Then tried `pod install` again and it worked.

Comment: I assume it works as I am in a different company now and not dealing with SpotX anymore. let's see if it helps other DEVs :)